# What is use case for -p flag in tee

Tags: linux, tee

Just reading the man page for tee, it says:

```
       -p     diagnose errors writing to non pipes
```

I'm just wondering what is the use case for this?

Comment: may I know which distro are you using...

Comment: @msp9011 ubuntu not sure which version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is equivalent to the full option `--output-error=warn-nopipe`. There is more explanation under the MODE list.

The default behaviour seems to be where tee has multiple outputs, maybe where stdout is to a pipe, or where a side output is through process substitution with `>( command )`, then if any reader of any pipe fails, tee exits. `-p` makes it continue with other outputs.

That's just my reading of the man page om Linux Mint: I have not tested any of this.